# truncecating data with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a parser using regex for JavaScript on the dataformated as follows:

```
2014-03-12 09:10:00;1157.998
```

There can be arbitrary data after the line and from what I can se there is \r\lf after the lines except the last line.

I only need the datetime and the mesurement with 3 decimals.
I've triend the following RegEx using:

```
dataStr.split(/(\d+[-]+\d+[-]+\d+\s+\d+[:]\d+[:]+\d+)+[;]+(\d+[.]+\d+)+(?![\r])/);
```

It's most likely thast there will be data after datatime and measurement but that data i will need to discart.
How is the discarting done?

/ryokan

Comment: Please give example of what you want extracted from the string above.

Comment: I need the data in two parts:
2014-03-12 09:10:00 and 1157.998 and ignore the rest following data.

Comment: show how the output should be

Comment: Ok, but please give a sample input and output expected

Comment: it's a function that takes a parameter function parseData(dataStr){var elements = dataStr.split(/(\d+[-]+\d+[-]+\d+\s+\d+[:]\d+[:]+\d+)+[;]+(\d+[.]+\d+)+(?![\r])/);}

console.log(elements[0]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dataStr = "2014-03-12 09:10:00;1157.998Junk\n2014-03-12 09:10:00;1157.998junkie";
var result = dataStr.split(/\n/).map(function(row) {

  var r = row.match(/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2});(\d+.\d{3})/)
      dateTime = new Date(r[1], Number(r[2]) - 1, r[3], r[4], r[5], r[6])

  return r ? {datetime: dateTime, number:Number(r[3])} : null
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

prints

`[{"datetime":"2014-03-12T03:40:00.000Z","number":12},{"datetime":"2014-03-12T03:40:00.000Z","number":12}]`

Please note `dateTime` is of Javascript datatype `Date`

Comment: datetime is a format where date and time are combined; otherwise and elegant solution. I need the values as you have guessed as a json obj :-)

Comment: Updated! Have a look!

Comment: You certainly live up to your name. I was able to adapt your sugestion to fit my problem. combining date and time into datetime.
I do however have a question:
What does the return ? {jsonobj data}  do? :)

Comment: Array map: It maps each array member to new value based on the return value of the called function. If regex parsing fails, r will be null. I check the value of r to ensure we have valid output.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do this:

You can use this regex:

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2});(\d+\.\d{3})
```

Use this code for the above regex:

```
var arr = [];
input.replace(/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2});(\d+\.\d{3})/,
function(match,g1,g2){
   arr.push[g1];
   arr.push[g2];
});
```

`arr` will have your required string

Comment: How about the new-lines?

Comment: @Teemu, what new lines?

Comment: From the question: "`There can be arbitrary data after the line and from what I can se there is \r\lf ...`".

Comment: The above is elegant but it puts the result on one line?
I need for datatime to be at pos 0 and measurement at pos 1 I've already gotten that but how do I discart any trialing data? :-)

Comment: @ryokan, arr[0] will contain datetime and arr[1] will contain the other data

Comment: True but the trailing data is also included in the array :-)

Comment: @ryokan, no. It won't contain trailing data

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2});(\d+(?:\.\d(?:\d\d?)?)?)
```

See it in action at http://regex101.com/r/pR8hZ2

Comment: It gives me:
elements: 2014-03-12 09:10:00
elements: 1157.998
elements: .998
elements: 98

I only need:
elements: 2014-03-12 09:10:00
elements: 1157.998

Comment: @ryokan I made the unneeded groups non-capturing, so that issue should be resolved.

Comment: sadly it includes the matching uneded groups in the resultset.